# Undefined Variable - PHP

Tags: php, variables, undeclared-identifier

I have a problem whit a variable which is not recognized inside my project, but it's declered properly. Here the specs of my files. I have an index.php controller like this:

```
            try {
                $sql = 'SELECT costi.id, costo, descrizione, categoria FROM costi INNER JOIN categorie ON id_categoria = categorie.id';
                $result = $pdo->query($sql);
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                $error = 'errore nel recupero del dato '. $e->getMessage();
                include 'error.html.php';
                exit();
            }   

            //FOREACH
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                $costi[] = array(
                    "id"=>$row['id'],
                    "costo"=>$row['costo'],
                    "descrizione"=>$row['descrizione'],
                    "categoria"=>$row['categoria']
                );
            }

            include 'review.html.php';
```

Here the review.html.php:

```
                <?php foreach($costi AS $costo): ?>
                    <table style="width:40%">
                    <form action="?cancella_costo" method="POST" >
                    <tr>
                        <th class="a"><p class="inline"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($costo['descrizione'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></p></th>
                        <th class="a"><p class="inline"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($costo['costo'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?> </p></th>
                        <th class="a"><p class="inline"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($costo['id_categoria'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?> </p></th>
                        <th class="none"><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $costo['id'] ?>" name="id"></th>
                        <th><input type="submit" value="cancella"></th>
                        <!-- <th><button name="action" value="update">Modifica</button></th> -->
                    </tr>

                    </form>
                    </table>
                <?php endforeach ?>
```

I also have a DB with two table: "costi" and "categorie" which are struccured like this:

costi:https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2aWH.jpg
categorie: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIy5g.jpg

My problem is the $costi variable declared inside my index.php and used inside my review.html.php. Inside this last file I get back this error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: costi in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/provePhp/myWallet 2/app/review.html.php on line 24

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/provePhp/myWallet 2/app/review.html.php on line 24
```

Did someone know why?
The variable is declared, why it's not recognized?

Comment: Where is it declared? Did you do `$costi = array();`?

Comment: In PHP, you technically don't need to declare a variable before you try to add array elements to it. But this often causes issues. I suspect your problem is that the variable is never declared on-the-fly in your foreach loop because `$result` is empty. Try `var_dump`ing it and see if it contains what you expect.

Comment: can you make me an example? I'm not getting what I have to do.

Answer (score 0):

From the piece of code you have pasted here, the variable $costi is not declared.

try changing it like below:

```
        $costi = [];
        // check whether the $result is array before looping
        if (is_array($result) {
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $costi[] = array(
                "id"=>$row['id'],
                "costo"=>$row['costo'],
                "descrizione"=>$row['descrizione'],
                "categoria"=>$row['categoria']
            );
        }
        }
```

Similarly you may check in view file as well before looping.

Comment: Just adding to this: the `$costi` variable is probably not getting defined because the query is failing, or is returning an empty result set.

Comment: I tried like you said "Prasanth Pillai". I don't get anymore the error but I also don't get any data from the costi and categorie tables using declaring the costi variable like this.

Comment: It could be because your SQL is returning no data. Copy the sql and execute in MySQL directly and see if you're getting any result first.

Comment: I don't get nothing from the query. Very strange because I have data inside the DB. What could it be the problem?

Comment: mate, without seeing data we can't comment. Please check whether there is matching records in both table for category id's

Answer (score 0):

OK I finally found the answer.
In my question I did forgot you to show also the "aggiungi_costo.php" file. It allow the user to add a cost to the DB.This was the file:

```
<form action="?" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="descrizione">Aggiunti la descrizione della spesa</label>
        <input type="text" id="descrizione" name="descrizione"> 
        <br>
        <label for="costo">Aggiungi l'importo della tua spesa</label>
        <input type="text" name="costo" id="costo">
        <br>
        <label for="id_categoria">A quale categoria apprtiene questa spesa:</label>
        <select multiple name="idcategoria" id="idcategoria">
        <?php foreach($categorie as $categoria): ?>
            <option><?php echo htmlspecialchars($categoria['categoria'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        </select>       
        </div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Aggiungi"></div>
</form>
```

I did forgot to ad the value attribute to the option tag (this string):

```
value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($categoria['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>"
```

Without it, my select query was unable to work because the "id.categoria" column didn't have a proper value sent from the "aggiungi_costo.php" form.

Adding the value attribute to the form, the query to add data to the DB start work properly and also the SELECT query to retrieve data start to work.